# Issue while installing protobuf in ubuntu 14.04 for go lang

Tags: go, protocol-buffers

I am following this documentation for installing the [golang protobuf](https://github.com/golang/protobuf) on ubuntu 14.04 for `go version go1.6 linux/amd64.` But it doesn't install the `protoc`. I am getting an error that protoc is not installed. Also, I have `$GOROOT/bin` in the path enviroment variable.

[image]

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/532701/how-can-i-install-protobuf-in-ubuntu-12-04

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message is clear to me, you have to install the `protoc` tool first, it is specified in the documentation: `Install the standard C++ implementation of protocol buffers from https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/`

Also, the error message says the same: on ubuntu system, there is a package containing this binary, which is `protobuf-compiler`.

The golang protobuf protoc-gen-go is merely a plugin of `protoc`, that's why you need `protoc` first.